# REST architecture compose list of objects on server or on client side?

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I want to make a page that displays a list of some objects (lets assume with some simple attributes like name, date and description), that could not be updated by user, that are updated rarely by the site administration. That number of this object could vary (and in most cases it is not a big number, approx. 5-10) and they are stored in a database. Should I use a rest resource (make a call from client site to the server that will return a JSON of objects) to load this list into the page view? Is it a downside that for such a simple page the user browser should make two requests to the server (first, to get html; second, to get a JSON with objects)? Could the page be pre-filled somehow on a server side to avoid double requests? Or any other tricks?

Comment: Can you give us some information which technologies do you use? Maybe the backend of your application.

Comment: Not sure of the reason you're considering to pull the information via rest services. If you can just load the data by doing a database query why would you all the work for the webservice?

Comment: @OdaYukimura I use c++ rest sdk (https://casablanca.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @nowhere I thought REST architecture assumes a complete decoupling of backend technology from html/js views.

Comment: @WscriChy Ok but this is only an advantage in some situations. Ie. when different clients based on different technologies all require to execute the same operation on some server. From what you wrote I don't understand what the need is for a rest WS.

Comment: @nowhere Do you mean that for the case I described REST idea could be meaningless? But I want to keep my html/js views independent from any template-backend technology (like jsp, php and etc.) What would you recommend then?

Comment: You said you want to "make a page that displays a list of some objects". If you mean a web page you will need to set a "layout" in html anyway. Also, to pull an information from a WS you need to use a server technology anyway (so you're actually just replacing the code making a query to the db with the code to request data from the rest WS).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97840/discussion-between-wscrichy-and-nowhere).